# При использовании lebab не читаются некоторые конструкции es5

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, prototype, es5

Я пытаюсь конвертировать из `es5` в `es6` используя [lebab](https://github.com/lebab/lebab).

`lebab es5.js -o es6.js --transform class`

Ечли я конвертирую простые куски кода, то все хорошо. Например:

```
var className = function(values) { this.__values = values; };
className.func = function() { return "test"; };
className.func2 = function() { return "test2"; };
className.prototype = {
    _values: null,  
    put: function() { return 0; },
    get_length: function() { return this._values.length; }
};
```

В

```
class com_cie_json_JsonArray {
    constructor(values) {
        this._values = values;
    }

    static func1() {
        return "test1";
    }

    static func2() {
        return "test2";
    }

    put() {
        return 0;
    }

    get_length() {
        return this._values.length;
    }
}
```

Но если в коде появвляются вставленые поля, то лебаб или конвертирует частично или не конвертирует совсем.
Вот такой код Уже для него не сильно валидный:

```
var className = function(values) {
    this.__values = values;
};
className.func = function() {
    return "test";
};
className.func2 = function() {
    return "test2";
};
$classes[2] = $classes["name.to.className"] = className;
className.__name__ = ["name","to","className"];
className.prototype = {
    _values: null,  
    put: function(value) {
        return 0;
    },
    get_length: function() {
        return this._values.length;
    },
    __class__: className,
    __properties__: {get_length:"get_length"}
};
```

Вопрос в том, как подобная конструкция будет выглядеть в ES6. И если это возможно как заставить `lebab` сконвертировать её в класс, потому что он вообще не конвертит именно такой кусок кода.

```
var className = function() {
};

$classes[2] = $classes["name.to.className"] = className;
className.__name__ = ["name","to","className"];

className.prototype = {
        _values: null,  
        __class__: className,
        __properties__: {get_length:"get_length"}
};

$classes[2] = $classes["name.to.className"] = className;
className.__name__ = ["name","to","className"];
```